# Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseExpoUpdatesAssets'

Tags: react-native, gradle

I got this error when I'm trying to build my react-native app :

> Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseExpoUpdatesAssets'.
>
> Process 'command './node_modules/expo-updates/run-expo.sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

What does it mean ? How can I solve this ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

skip this task using this command

```
./gradlew assembleRelease -x ':app:bundleReleaseExpoUpdatesAssets'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have used expo to build your project try this steps
1. run command `expo publish` 
2. then try `./gradlew bundleRelease` for your apk build.

Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

Currently without expo publish you can't create release build in expo ejected app. Which i think you've done, otherwise this task ':app:bundleReleaseExpoUpdatesAssets' will not get added in project created from bare React Native app.

I'm still unclear with `expo publish` need, that is why can't we create our own bundle with `npx react-native bundle` command and use it? and once I'm clear will update answer with my findings.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with expo init bare workflow project also.. Same issue not working.